# How to write two different routes but calling same controller function in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

There two different routes but it calling the same controller function.

two possible routes:

```
1) ios-mobile-developer-india
2) salesforce-consultant-india
```

we are technology and location dynamically.

routes.rb:

```
get ':tech-mobile-developer-:loc' => application#tech_location
get ':tech-consultant-:loc' => application#tech_location
```

If i search ios-consultant-india, it 'll show the output. But, I want to redirect to ios-consultant-india. can anyone tell how to redirect based on  technology?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this `get '/stories', to: redirect('/articles')`

[routing redirect](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

Comment: yes, it 's redirect successfully. But, I need to set constraint in routes., That is, Based on params[:tech], routes to be selected. likewise., if 'ios' means, select 'ios-mobile-developer-india'. if 'sap' means, select 'sap-consultant-india'. (Based on params[:tech], to select the routes automatically.).How to set constraints for this condition?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a redirect at route level, you may want to use the [router redirect feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection).

```
get '/:tech-mobile-developer-:loc', to: redirect('/%{tech}-consultant-%{loc}')
```

In this way you don't need to inject the redirect code in the action itself, and the action will only contain the code responsible to render the action content.

Comment: yes, it 's redirect successfully. But, I need to set constraint in routes., That is, Based on params[:tech], routes to be selected. likewise., if 'ios' means, select 'ios-mobile-developer-india'. if 'sap' means, select 'sap-consultant-india'. (Based on params[:tech], to select the routes automatically.).How to set constraints for this condition?